# How to access the remote server for storing and retrieving files through android

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am working on my final year project. I am doing a project in android to store and retrieve files from remote web server. I am new to android programming. I want code for accessing the remote web server to store and retrieve files. Can you please help me by providing the code for client side and server side???

Answer (score 2):

We can't do the work for you, but we can put you on the right track and give you the directions.  To start with, you will (most likely) need to use classes [org.apache.http.client.HTTPClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html) and [org.apache.http.client.HttpURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html).

And here is a link to a [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidNetworking/article.html) on how to use this class.

Putting the two together, doing what you need should be simple.